# How to attach custom image as a particle in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm wanting to make a rain scene in After Effects using the particle generator. However I want to use my own custom rain drop graphic. How can I achieve this?

Here is a still of what I'm talking about:

http://i1056.photobucket.com/albums/t364/Robert_Koh/rain-example_zps0dql6xtz.jpg

Comment: I am not sure about the built in particle system, but there is a (paid) plug in called 'Trapcode Particular' that does exactly that and much more.

Answer (score 2):

In the AE stock particle plug in, find the tab for Source, and link your .png file of the raindrops to become the source. All particle plugins pretty much do the same thing, however, Trapcode Particular does it with ease.

Download the Demo, and use the Effects Builder to create a customised template of how you want the particles to generate, then tweak away at the settings to further modify the effect. It also allows you to easily import a Sprite (your rain drop .png) and that will become the particle itself.